# Intelli J idea coding reformatting. When i type and hit enter code below does not shift down one line

Tags: intellij-idea

I think i hit something or did something while learning to code in java on intelliJ idea. My code below which is just two lines of }} are not moving down so when i enter it types over them. so i have to actively manually enter them downwards

Answer (score 0):

did you hit the insert button? that is normally my problem when overwriting vs inserting.

is it overwritting everything or just when you hit return?